# Convert List<Class<*>> to List<KClass<*>>

Tags: kotlin

I have a Kotlin method that returns a `List<Class<*>>` - here:

```
val findAllAnnotatedClassesInPackage =
            findAllAnnotatedClassesInPackage("com.eaample.domain", Entity::class.java)
        assertNotNull(findAllAnnotatedClassesInPackage)
```

How can I convert this to `Iterable<KClass<*>>`

```
myClassList.map { 
  it.somethingThatReturnsKClass()
}
```

KClass is an interface, so how do I get an implementation of it from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving the question, because I think it's a fair one and Googling did not get me much of an answer.

Looks like `it.kotlin` was the answer, as simple as that is.

```
myClassList.map { 
  it.kotlin
}
```